# Cannot run Java Spring application

Tags: java, spring-boot

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

**EcommerceApplication.java**

```
package com.ecommerce.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class EcommerceApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EcommerceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/metrics/ApplicationStartup
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>(SpringApplication.java:247)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>(SpringApplication.java:262)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1342)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1331)
    at com.ecommerce.demo.EcommerceApplication.main(EcommerceApplication.java:9)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.metrics.ApplicationStartup
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 5 more
```

I got stuck when trying to run Spring application even I added the dependency on `pom.xml` it still could not work as expected so where could I fix the problem to have the application run smoothly?

I tried to figure out the solution by doing research from the Internet but the problem still could not be fixed

Answer (score 2):

This could be because of the version mismatch between the Spring boot starter and the Spring version.

When you are using SpringBoot you don't have to specify the version for spring dependencies explicitly. Just specify the spring-boot-starter-parent version in your pom.xml. See the below starter pom using [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io/).

If you are trying to create a new project I suggest using [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io/) to have a basic skeleton of the project and/or pom.xml. And from there on you can keep adding the dependencies as required.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
    <relativePath/>
    <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>demo</name>
  <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
  <properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```